# Qtranslate-X get raw post title value

Tags: translation, multi-language, language

How can I get a raw value of post title using Qtranslate-X plugin? 
I have 2 active languages - [:et] and [:ru]

```
$posts = get_posts($args);
if($posts){
    foreach($posts as $post){

       $title1 = $post->post_title;
       $title2 = get_post_field( 'post_title', $post->ID, 'raw' );

       echo $title1;
       echo $title2;

    }
}
```

Variables $title1 and $title2 returns only [:et] versions of a title.
Database value of post_title is:

```
[:et]Immuniseerimise jätkukursus[:ru]Иммунизация – дополнительный курс[:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**post_title_ml** property should be used to get a raw post value, instead of **post_title**

```
$title = $post->post_title_ml
```

To translate raw value **translate_text** filter can be used

```
$english_title = apply_filters('translate_text', $title, 'en');
```

Or **qtranxf_use_language()** function

```
$english_title = qtranxf_use_language('en', $title, false, true);
```